# Stripe discount on upcoming payment of recurring subscription

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-customer-portal

I have implemented stripe recurring subscription that billed annually. I've proposed an offer for my customers that if they refer our website to 5 of their friends and they register, they will get 50% off on their subscription.

How I'll implement that discount for that particular customer on next payment?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest option would be to apply a [Coupon](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/coupons) to the customer’s subscription. Then during the next billing cycle of the subscription, the coupon will be automatically applied. That can be done is two steps (here done node.js):

```js
// Create the new Coupon, once
// Doc: https://stripe.com/docs/api/coupons/create
const coupon = await stripe.coupons.create({
  percent_off: 50,
  duration: 'once', // other possible value are 'forever' or 'repeating'
});

// Then every time a customer match your criteria, update their subscription
// Doc: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.update(
  'sub_xxx',
  { coupon: coupon.id }
);
```

Another option would be to apply the coupon to the customer instead of on the subscription directly. In that case the coupon would apply to all recurring charges for that customer.

```js
// Doc: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update
const customer = await stripe.customers.update(
  'cus_xxx',
  { coupon: coupon.id }
);
```